# FullCalendar dayClick not triggering

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I had issue when dayClick function was't triggering on page with scroll for some cells and it was fine for others. Basically it was fine on page without scroll, but on longer content having page it cause problem.

Comment: Are the js files in place ? How are you trying to get the pop up? Using an alert or using Bootstrap Modal or any other css methods ? I guess the default one is to get a inputbox from javascript.

Comment: All files were out of the box,  problem was because I had no parent element with css property 'overflow', please read answer below

Answer (score 3):

What I have found out is that there is two functions to define cell position in grid ( fullcalendar 2.5.0 version):

'getHorizontalIndex' and 'getVerticalIndex'

Function 'getVerticalIndex' return 'undefined' because mouse 'topOffset' position was out of 'boundingRect' dimensions, so after digging deeper I found out function 'getScrollParent' (line 297) which is responsible for finding top parent element.

```
function getScrollParent(el) {
    var position = el.css('position');
    var scrollParent = el.parents().filter(function() {
        var parent = $(this);
        return (/(auto|scroll)/).test(
            parent.css('overflow') + parent.css('overflow-y') + parent.css('overflow-x')
        );
    }).eq(0);

    return position === 'fixed' || !scrollParent.length ? $(el[0].ownerDocument || document) : scrollParent;
}
```

and because in my css were no elements with css 'overflow:scroll' or 'overflow:auto' my parent element was 'html' which height was detected as height without scroll.
Solution was simple - specify 'overflow:auto;' in css for calendar element. For example, if you have code like:

```
<div id="mycalendar"></div>

(function(){
    $("#mycalendar").fullCalendar({});
})();
```

add style 'overflow:auto;' for 'mycalendar' div.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Traces out the entire problem through to the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The current fix is to remove `overflow-x: hidden` from the HTML element. Its a known issue: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3615